# Difference between ritual, festival, and ceremony

Tags: meaning, differences

I am trying draw a line of distinction between these three events.

As I understand it:

> Ritual is somewhat related to a religion.
>   Festival is associated with a group of people and that brings happiness.
>   Ceremony is something that is followed by a group of individuals before performing a task.

Can someone please tell me if I am wrong, and also provide some examples?

Comment: Perhaps you could also try a dictionary?

Comment: Close, glance in dictionary

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ceremonies and Rituals can for the most part be interchanged, however most people will associate ceremonies more with organized religion (such as a church service) or events of achievement, such as a graduation ceremony. Rituals seem to give a cultish vibe - or something considered more tribal - such as an ancient Mayan ritual.

Festivals, on the other hand, generally do not have to do with ceremonies or rituals. Festivals are events that people attend in large numbers to have fun. Some examples of festivals are carnivals, fairs, beer-fests, and so on.

Comment: But a ritual can also be something entirely personal, something you do on a regular basis that helps you get through the day (or the work week, or whatever). Making coffee is part of my morning ritual, for example.

Comment: @Nicholas, you are absolutely right. In the context of ceremonies and festivals, I forgot about this use of `ritual`, which is probably the most used case in general contexts.

Answer (score 3):

*Ritual* can also mean "a series of actions or type of behavior regularly and invariably followed by someone"; in such case, there is not relation with religions.

*Festival* can be used to mean "a day or period of celebration, typically a religious commemoration," or "an annual celebration or anniversary." In the first case, the word is related to religions.

*Ceremony* can mean "a formal religious or public occasion, typically one celebrating a particular event or anniversary," or " the ritual observances and procedures performed at grand and formal occasions." In the first case, also this word is related to religions.

Comment: isn't ritual more related to a religion or a community ?

Answer (score 1):

I think it’s important to note that rituals can happen within festival/carnival, not just can, but do.

The idea of going into a bordered space to relieve oneself of the pressures of the everyday and coming out transformed is ritualistic. One can narrow it down even further to the rituals that take place during carnival. Check out theorist Mikhael Bakhtin.

Answer (score 0):

Rituals and even more so, ceremonies seem to have a political purpose, Celebrations and festivals less so. Ivaylo

Comment: A **political** purpose?! Could you elaborate?

Comment: Hello, and Welcome to EL&U. Thanks for your input. We like answers to be fact based, not solely opinion based, and as such, love to see links to sources which support your answer whenever possible. :-)